# How to get real-time database updates to the client without always getting all the data per screen/query?

Tags: mysql, database, azure, state, price

So I've a client which needs all the data shown to him per screen to be always the latest & most correct data. If he's afk for a while he knows to refresh and it's fine, however per "refresh" or database call, all the latest data has to be get.

Right now I've just implemented that for each time a screen is rendered, the data will be get from the DB. This is an SQL database btw.

Now we might want to deploy it in the future to Azure, however ALWAYS getting so much data per screen/call etc... will end up being very pricy I assume.

How to solve this issue? "Only" caching isn't really a solution I think, because how else will the front-end know new changes to the database have been made (records added, edited, etc...)? Do we need some sort of "observers" on our database to push changes to the caching when new changes happen?

We're already working somewhat with Redux (it's a ReactJs app) but of course, how will the internal front-end app-state know if something to the DB was added by say, another person?

If Person A loads all data and person B adds an entity, if person A refreshes I need all LATEST changes get from the DB, but technically without always getting all data, because that would become expensive...

I hope you understand what I mean. How can I fix this issue and what's the best (and also perhaps most cost effective & most performant way) of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a communication from server to client where new/changed data will be passed. You can do it using Web Sockets or Server Side Events:

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API